# Interpolating NA values within group (long-format data)

Tags: r, dplyr, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate missing NA values within a data frame that is in "long-format," but am having trouble. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

#step 1 - write data frame
df <- tibble(day=1:10,
             walmart =  c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 7, 8 , 9, 10),
             amazon= c(10, 15, 20, NA, 30, 35, 40, NA, 50, 55))

#step 2 - convert to long format 
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= c(walmart, amazon),
               names_to = "company",
               values_to = "sales")

#step 3 - perform interpolation
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sales=na.approx(sales))
```

Evidently, the interpolation is not taking into account the two different stores. I would like to interpolate the missing values for walmart based on the surrounding values for walmart only, and the missing values for amazon based on the surrounding values for amazon only. I do recognize that performing the interpolation with the data in wide format (as it is after step 1) on each column (in this case walmart and amazon) is possible, but I am trying to avoid doing this with my actual data because a) there are thousands of "companies" and b) I want to interpolate several variables so by transposing the data I would just put myself back in the same position. Moreover, I don't thinking using group_by(company) will work because that yields a size error with na.approx. Is there a way to resolve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `company` (not `sales`):

```r
df %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(sales=zoo::na.approx(sales)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#      day company sales
#    <int> <chr>   <dbl>
#  1     1 walmart     1
#  2     1 amazon     10
#  3     2 walmart     2
#  4     2 amazon     15
#  5     3 walmart     3
#  6     3 amazon     20
#  7     4 walmart     4
#  8     4 amazon     25
#  9     5 walmart     5
# 10     5 amazon     30
# 11     6 walmart     6
# 12     6 amazon     35
# 13     7 walmart     7
# 14     7 amazon     40
# 15     8 walmart     8
# 16     8 amazon     45
# 17     9 walmart     9
# 18     9 amazon     50
# 19    10 walmart    10
# 20    10 amazon     55
```

Since you're running into errors in your use, that suggests that you have `NA`s on either end of a company's set of values. For instance,

```r
df$amazon[10] <- NA
df
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#      day walmart amazon
#    <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     1       1     10
#  2     2       2     15
#  3     3       3     20
#  4     4       4     NA
#  5     5      NA     30
#  6     6      NA     35
#  7     7       7     40
#  8     8       8     NA
#  9     9       9     50
# 10    10      10     NA
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= c(walmart, amazon),
               names_to = "company",
               values_to = "sales")
df %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(sales=zoo::na.approx(sales)) %>%
  ungroup()
Error in `mutate()`:
# ! Problem while computing `sales = zoo::na.approx(sales)`.
# x `sales` must be size 10 or 1, not 9.
# i The error occurred in group 1: company = "amazon".
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The issue with this is that `zoo::na.approx` is shortening your vector. Consider this:

```r
zoo::na.approx(c(1,NA,3))
# [1] 1 2 3
zoo::na.approx(c(1,NA,3,NA))
# [1] 1 2 3
zoo::na.approx(c(1,NA,3,NA), na.rm=FALSE)
# [1]  1  2  3 NA
```

So add `na.rm=FALSE` to your call to `na.approx`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(sales=zoo::na.approx(sales, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 20 x 3
#      day company sales
#    <int> <chr>   <dbl>
#  1     1 walmart     1
#  2     1 amazon     10
#  3     2 walmart     2
#  4     2 amazon     15
#  5     3 walmart     3
#  6     3 amazon     20
#  7     4 walmart     4
#  8     4 amazon     25
#  9     5 walmart     5
# 10     5 amazon     30
# 11     6 walmart     6
# 12     6 amazon     35
# 13     7 walmart     7
# 14     7 amazon     40
# 15     8 walmart     8
# 16     8 amazon     45
# 17     9 walmart     9
# 18     9 amazon     50
# 19    10 walmart    10
# 20    10 amazon     NA
```

Note that since this is doing *interpolation*, the `NA` values outside of the known range will not be replaced. If you need that, consider what form of *extrapolation* you need.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, that it was I meant to say in the question. That works for this example, but when I use group_by on my real dataset, I get an error stating "variable but by size 21 or 1, not 7" or something along those lines. I previously removed NA values, and this error does not occur when I don't group, though the interpolation doesn't work. This solution seems to be correct though so it may be something else in the data. I just thought it was too large to post here. Thanks!

Comment: I understand. See my edit for a likely solution.

Comment: thank you! Adding na.rm=FALSE did in fact solve the problem.